# How to include interactive plotting in scatter plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-interactive

I have a scatter plot looking like this:

[image]

Each point in this image describes average hardness value taken over 5 points of data, in each batch. So for each point a hardness plot can be generated with the data. I want to know how to code in interactive mode in Python, such that when I hover my mouse to each point, the image of hardness plot will pop up?

Comment: Could you please add [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your post to demonstrate an effort of solving the issue and making the question more specific?

Comment: Are you using python2 or python3? Please don't tag both.

Comment: Go to the "How this works" section of [this](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/01/10/d3-plugins-truly-interactive/) post. Specifically, the plot above "Side Note: Why Am I Doing This?". This is very similar to what you need.